# Late Cross of Kaplan-Meier Curves - Does it matter?

Tags: cox-model, assumptions, kaplan-meier

Does a late cross of Kaplan-Meier curves necessarily violate the proportional hazards assumption?

I have seen it argued (e.g. [here](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?stat_the_hazard_ratio.htm)) that it matters less if the curves cross late in the graph because there is less data available at that point to calculate the curves from. The 95% confidence windows of the curve estimates are therefore more likely to overlap, but it's less damning than an overlap early in the curve because it's more possible that the true curves are still proportional.

Is this a reasonable argument? 
Is there another argument you could make to excuse a late cross?

The example in the paper I am looking at crosses when roughly 3 out of 300 patients are left in the study.

Comment: I would not be worried about the non-proportional hazards if the KM curves where there were only 3 patients left.